# Translation of definition into logical proposition.

Tags: logic

I want to translate the following definition into logical proposition.

There is a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$,$g:X \rightarrow Y$. $f=g$ is for all $x$, $f(x)=g(x)$.

What I've done is this.

$$f=g \Leftrightarrow \forall x : [x \in D \rightarrow f(x)=g(x)]$$

Does it right?

However there arises a problem when $a \not \in D$. When $a \not \in D$, the assumption that $x \in D$ is false, so that the logical proposition is vacously true.

What is wrong with my translation?

Comment: I don't see any trouble with that. However, writing $f(x)=g(x)$ makes no sense when $x\notin X$, so I would prefer writing something like$$f=g\iff \forall x\in X\ [ f(x)=g(x)].$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your translation is that $D$ is undefined. There are two cases. If $f$ and $g$ are (total) functions, then the version proposed by Arnaud in its comment is the correct one. If $f$ and $g$ are partial functions, you have to introduce a notation for their domain, which is not necessarily the same. If you denote by $D(f)$ and $D(g)$ the respective domains of $f$ and $g$, then
could write, in logical terms
$$
f = g \iff \bigl(D(f) = D(g)\bigr) \wedge \bigl(\forall x \in D(f)\ \ f(x) = g(x)\bigr)
$$
or, if want more details
$$
f = g \iff \Bigl(\forall x \in X\ \bigl(x \in D(f) \iff x \in D(g)\bigr)\Bigr) \wedge \Bigl(\forall x \in D(f)\ \ f(x) = g(x)\Bigr)
$$